# Clean form when return back

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if there is the possibility of going to clean up the fields of a form when you return back to the site by clicking on the back button of the browser.
I have the problem that in the home of my site I have a form that leads to research in another page if the user presses the back button of the browser instead of the link I posted to get back, the previous form is loaded with data the previous search.
Can I create a Javascript that even when you press back he manages to reload the form?
I think there is a problem that the page on the back does not recharge the html code

Comment: It's a bad idea to mess with the way the back button works unless you have a very, very good reason. I'd just give them a reset button on the page and let the user use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `reset()` method on the form object

Example:

```
document.getElementById("myform").reset();
```

See below link for further info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to trigger an action before the user leaves the page...

```
<body onbeforeunload="return ExitFunction()">
```